# Duplicate and destroy an EC2 instance in AWS via .NET code

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, worker

We have an application with long running processes which prevents us from being able to use Elastic Beanstalk to properly scale the environment. In fact no metric scaling would be useful for us and what we really need to be able to do is the following....

- On demand, programatically, create a new EC2 instance which is a duplicate of a specific EC2 "template" instance  (That template instance would be an EC2 running IIS with specific code deployed to it, probably via beanstalk).
- On demand, programatically, destroy a specific instance

Based on specific events we would need to perform the above actions via our .NET code base.

I get the feeling that we should be able to do this with cloudformation templates but i dont see any clear documentation to handle this.

Any advise or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about doing this through .Net code, but you can create an auto scaling group in AWS console and that will take care of the scaling requirements in a maintainable way.

1. Log on to AWS and navigate to Management Console
2. First create an EC2 Instance with proper instance type (say, t2.large) or whatever your sizing is.
3. Then have IIS installed and get your app running on this instance.
4. Now create a new Image from the above running EC2 Instance
5. Create a new Auto Scaling Group and add the above new Image
6. Create a Launch Configuration for the Auto Scaling Group (AWS Console will redirect you to do this step when you try to setup Auto Scaling Group).
7. Once the Auto Scaling Group is setup, navigate to Auto Scaling Policy and add a policy there. For example, you can create a policy to 'add 1 instance on CPU utilization of 80% or more for 2 consecutive times'.
8. Also make sure Min is 0 and Max is say, 2. This is upto you to decide based on your scaling requirements. If you have Min as 1, it automatically creates the first instance. If Min is 0, no new instances will be created until the threshold in the Auto Scale Policy is met.
9. Also create a Scale Down Policy to remove instances when there is a low CPU utilization.

Note: I took CPU utilization as an example to describe the scenario. You can have any metrics as per your choice and architectural needs.